# How do you do hide an empty ACF field using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields

I figured that I would simplify my question.
This could be a PHP problem so I apologize in advanced because this may not be an ACF issue but it could be an issue of me not knowing enough PHP, I'm not sure why this isn’t working.

So I am using the ACF repeater field and I would like to hide the repeater Subfield when no data is entered in the field.

```
    <?php

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data

    $feature_posts = the_sub_field('feature_image_post');

    if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):

      // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value
              echo '<div style="float:left">';
                the_sub_field('restaurant_name');
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div style="float:left">';
                the_sub_field('restaurant_state');
              echo '</div>';

              echo '<div style="float:left">';
                the_sub_field('restaurant_image_post');
               echo '</div>';  

                  if (empty($feature_posts)) {
                    echo '<div style="display:none">';
                    the_sub_field('feature_image_post');
                    echo '</div>'; 
                  } 

                  else {

                      the_sub_field('feature_image_post');
                  }

        endwhile;

    else :

        // no rows found

    endif;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional statement using `get_sub_field` to check if the field is empty. `the_sub_field` echos the value and `get_sub_field` returns the value, so it can be used in a conditional statement or stored in a variable.

```
if( get_sub_field('restaurant_name') != "" ) {
  echo '<div style="float:left">';
  the_sub_field('restaurant_name');
  echo '</div>';
}
```